# installed.packages() doesn't show priority

Tags: r, package, install.packages

When I run the `installed.packages()` command in the console in order to see which packages I have installed and which loaded, I get the following:

> installed.packages()
> Package         LibPath                                          Version   Priority
> askpass       "askpass"       "C:/Users/sergi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2" "1.1"     NA
> assertthat    "assertthat"    "C:/Users/sergi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2" "0.2.1"   NA
> backports     "backports"     "C:/Users/sergi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2" "1.4.1"   NA
> base64enc     "base64enc"     "C:/Users/sergi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2" "0.1-3"   NA

As you can see, all packages have 'NA' as their value in the priority column, thus one can't really know which ones are loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `priority` is `NULL` or `NA`.  According to `?installed.packages

> priority - character vector or NULL (default). If non-null, used to select packages; **"high" is equivalent to c("base", "recommended")**. To select all packages without an assigned priority use priority = "NA".

If we want to get the packages with `high` priority, use

```
installed.packages(priority = "high")
```

-checking

```
> head(installed.packages(priority = "high")[, 
       c("Package", "Version", "Priority")] )
          Package     Version  Priority     
base      "base"      "4.2.0"  "base"       
boot      "boot"      "1.3-28" "recommended"
class     "class"     "7.3-20" "recommended"
cluster   "cluster"   "2.1.3"  "recommended"
codetools "codetools" "0.2-18" "recommended"
compiler  "compiler"  "4.2.0"  "base"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! However, when I run installed.packages(priority = "high"), there are packages that I have installed and loaded that are missing, such as ggplot2:                      
base       "base"       "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library" "4.2.1"   "base"       

foreign    "foreign"    "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library" "0.8-82"  "recommended"
graphics   "graphics"   "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library" "4.2.1"   "base"       
grDevices  "grDevices"  "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library" "4.2.1"   "base"

Comment: @SergioArencibia the high stands for base and recommended.  So, possibly ggplot2 may not come under the recommended (and it is certainly not a base R package)